# number of permutations in which all number changes

Tags: permutations

> What is the number of permutations in which all number change
> position?
>
> For example, suppose a ordered set (12345678...n)
>
> What is the number of permutations this (below) is not allowed:
>
> Let P be, let's say, the permutation operator, and a_{i} the element
> at the i position
>
> Apply now P on the set, if $ai_{after, p} = ai_{before, p}$ for some
> i, so it is not allowed.

I am a little stuck because, i think we can not separate in little cases as, for example, "n! - (number o situations in which 1 remains 1)..." Since if we try that, we will need to consider the cases in which, let's say, 2 go for 1 or for another, and so on...

Answer (score 1):

This is called a "[derangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement)."